# How to Call properly Fragment from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I have Fragment which i call from the MainActivity Class :-) .

Here is the fragment code :

```
public class PersonFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_NAME = "name";
private static final String ARG_FIRSTNAME = "firstname";

ListView lst;


String[] name = {"Dockar","Nilson"};

String[] firstname = {"Jack","Michel"};


public static PersonFragment newInstance(String[] name, String[] firstname) {
    PersonFragment fragment = new PersonFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray(ARG_NAME, name);
    args.putStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;

}

Activity mainActivity;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.person_fragment, container, false);

    lst = view.findViewById(R.id.listviewperson);
    CustomeListviewAdapterTest customeListview = new CustomeListviewAdapterTest(this.mainActivity,name,firtname);
    lst.setAdapter(customeListview);

    lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            if(position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Jack.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }if(position == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Michel.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } 
        }
    });

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        name = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_NAME);
        firstname = getArguments().getStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME);

    }

    return view;
}
```

I don't know if everything is OK, i don't have error on Android Studio IDE.

Now i want to call it from the MainActivity. So i Put this one on a Menu :

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.drawer_person:
            PersonFragment fragment = PersonFragment.newInstance(HAVE ERROR HERE);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            break;
```

On the newInstance(), i don't know how to call the String Data from my Array :

String[] name

And

String[] firstname

Can someone help how i can do that ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to pass string arrays name and firstname to your `PersonFragment` when you create an instance of it. To do that, you need to modify the newInstance method to accept these arrays as parameters. Here's how you can do it:

In your `PersonFragment` class, modify the newInstance method as follows:

```
public static PersonFragment newInstance(String[] name, String[] firstname) {
    PersonFragment fragment = new PersonFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putStringArray(ARG_NAME, name);
    args.putStringArray(ARG_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Now, in your `MainActivity`, you can call this method with your string arrays as parameters like this:

```
PersonFragment fragment = PersonFragment.newInstance(name, firstname);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This way, you are passing the name and firstname arrays to the PersonFragment when you create an instance of it, and these values will be accessible within the fragment. Your code should work correctly with this modification.

Comment: Hello Gaston, Thank you for your reply :) . The code you give about the NewInstance above is just the same i have ? Did you forget something on it ? On my MainActivity i put name, firstname like you say but it doesn't work. It says: Cannot Resolve Symbol 'name' and  Cannot Resolve Symbol 'fistname' :( .